# Hiding <th> element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to hide some table element by JavaScript
For `<td>` element it's OK:

```
function hide(){  
    var x=document.getElementsByTagName('td');  
    for(var i in x){  
        x[i].style.visibility='hidden';  
    }  
}
```

But when I did the same with `<th>` elements it's not OK

```
function hide(){  
    var x=document.getElementsByTagName('th');  
    for(var i in x){  
        x[i].style.visibility='hidden';  
    }  
}
```

Some body please tell me why? And how I can manage?

Here's my HTML

```
<table>  
    <thead>  
        <tr>  
            <th>header 1</th>  
            <th>header 2</th>  
            <th>header 3</th>  
        </tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody>  
        <tr>  
            <td>content 1.1</td>  
            <td>content 1.2</td>  
            <td>content 1.3</td>  
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>content 2.1</td>  
            <td>content 2.2</td>  
            <td>content 2.3</td>  
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
```

There's a strange thing
when I do this

```
function hide(){  
    var x=document.getElementsByTagName('td');  
    for(var i in x){  
        x[i].style.visibility='hidden';  
    }  
    var y=document.getElementsByTagName('th');  
    for(var i in y){  
        y[i].style.visibility='hidden';  
    }  
}
```

The function is not working correctly, just  elements hide, the  still visible.

But when I separate into two function, it workes correctly.

I'm using Chrome.
Why has this happened?

Comment: looks fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5fnT8/).Please post your html markup

Comment: can  you share relevant html code as well? also how are you calling the `hide` function for both `<td>` and `<th>`?

Comment: There is an in issue with this in Chrome at least. Since the `for` will include `length` at some point, at the end of the loop javascript will throw an error.

Comment: Put your HTML into @Pilot's fiddle, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5fnT8/1/

Comment: @anurupr I put onclick in two button. The function name just for example.

Comment: @David I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `for-in` to iterate over a `NodeList`. The NodeList object has properties that aren't elements of the list. It gets an error when `i` is `"length"`, because `x["length"]` doesn't have a `style` property.

```
function hide(){  
    var x=document.getElementsByTagName('th');  
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){  
        x[i].style.visibility='hidden';  
    }  
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5fnT8/3/)

Answer (score 1):

as per Barmar.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x=document.getElementsByTagName('th');  
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){  
         x[i].style.display ='none';  
    }   
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/r5Ua5/